# text not appearing on console in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

```
    Console.WriteLine("Choose a city. (if you need help, type list for a list of cities you can destroy.)")
    Console.ReadLine()
    Dim cityList As String = "new york city, carmel, LA, chicago. (we only support detonations for new york city at this point in time.)"

    If Console.ReadLine = "list" Then
        Console.WriteLine(cityList)
        Console.ReadLine()

    End If
```

'I just have no idea why this isn't working

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `Console.ReadLine()` twice. You need to either remove the first one, or set a variable equal to the first one (and remove the second), then check if it is equal to `"list"`.

Examples:

```
Console.WriteLine("Choose a city. (if you need help, type list for a list of cities you can destroy.)")
Dim cityList As String = "new york city, carmel, LA, chicago. (we only support detonations for new york city at this point in time.)"

If Console.ReadLine = "list" Then
    Console.WriteLine(cityList)
    Console.ReadLine()
End If
```

Or store the variable:

```
Console.WriteLine("Choose a city. (if you need help, type list for a list of cities you can destroy.)")
Dim input As String = Console.ReadLine() ' Store the variable
Dim cityList As String = "new york city, carmel, LA, chicago. (we only support detonations for new york city at this point in time.)"

If input = "list" Then ' Check the stored input
    Console.WriteLine(cityList)
    Console.ReadLine()
End If
```